# Using vimrc function to pass python arguments

Tags: python, vim

I am attempting to create a vimrc function that will be used in an `autocmd`. The function must simply call a python script and pass the file name as an argument.

*.vimrc*

```
fu! Test(filename)
    let filename = expand("%:t")
    "echom filename
    !test.py filename
```

*example.py*

```
#!usr/bin/python
import sys

print sys.argv[1]
```

If I uncomment the echo line, `example.py` is echo'd correctly. If I try to execute as it is displayed above, however, the string `filename` is passed literally.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use the `execute` command to execute a string, which is built from the command you want and the variable concatenated together:

```
fu! Test()
    let filename = expand("%:t")
    execute "!test.py " . l:filename
endfunction
```

I've omitted the filename argument in your `Test` function because it doesn't seem to be used

Answer (score 1):

You have two options either you pass the filename directly as an argument or pass it as a local variable:

```
fu! Test(filename)
    "echom a:filename
    execute "!test.py ".a:filename
```

or

```
fu! Test()
    let l:filename = expand("%:t")
    "echom filename
    execute "!test.py ". l:filename
```